# Convert multibyte utf-8 char to single unicode hex representation

Tags: c++, unicode, binary, hex

I'm trying to convert multibyte chars to a single hex representation in C++.

I want to compare certain characters to some unicode hex ranges, can handle single byte binary to hex conversion of course, confusion comes when there's multiple bytes for a character, how do I resolve multiple bytes into a single hex, convert and add? or do I convert as one gigantic  binary number?

Illustration

詳: 11101000 10101001 10110011

詳: E8 A9 B3

But how do I correctly resolve it into a single value.

Comment: Most Unicode can be represented in 24 bits.  I recommend using a 32-bit unsigned integer.  Some languages may need more than 24 bits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "*Most Unicode can be represented in 24 bits*" - the entire Unicode codepoint repertoire fits in 21 bits. The highest codepoint defined is 0x10FFFF

Comment: Note: a glyph (or character, e.g. for fonts) may uses more then one code point. Usually "COMBINING" codepoints should be keep together, but then many languages may use some sort of "ligatures" (which often are totally different characters). And to add confusion: same (equivalent) characters can have many different codepoint strings, so usually we transform unicode strings into their CANONICAL FORM. Note: if you are using UTF-8, the first byte of a codepoint has well known ranges (0-0x7F, 0xC2-0xF4), and such bytes are always the first byte of a UTF-8 codepoint. (UTF-8 is self-syncronizing)